# creating complex JSON using BasicNameValuePair

Tags: java, android, basicnamevaluepair, android-httptransport

How can I create this JSON using ArrayList for posting json in Android

```
{
"user" : 
    {
        "nickname" : "nickname6",
        "password" : "1234",
    }
}
```

I get only to a flat JSON

```
    ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();

    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nickname","nickname6"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "1234"));
```

Comment: I just want to note that `NameValuePair and BasicNameValuePair have been deprecated ` i recomand to learn something new

Comment: If you are using ArrayList, then can you please explain your output format in brief?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a JSON, and for that you have to add that JSON as a parameter in your POST method. To do that you can try this :

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONObject joParams = json.getJSONObject("params");
String nickname = joParams.getString("nickname");

    post.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nickname", nickname);
```

Comment: If this answer helpful to you, please accept this answer as you have seen the tickmark below the vote, so more and more people will know about this answer.

Answer (score 2):

As you know, HttpClasses, NameValuePair and BasicNameValuePair have been deprecated in latest android. we should avoid it now.

and If you want to create

```
{
   "user":{
        "nickname":"nickname6"
        "password":"1234",             
    }
}
```

Than you can use below code sample to create the same json using JSONObject class.

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();

try {       
    JSONObject userCredentials = new JSONObject();
    userCredentials.put("nickname","nickname6");
    userCredentials.put("password","1234");

    jObj.put("user", userCredentials);
} catch(Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: What are the alternative for HttpClasses, NameValuePair and BasicNameValuePair? you have a good example for simple post action? Thank you.

Comment: Use HttpURLConnection, this is the good ( best ) alternative for HttpClasses.

Comment: @user1684140 : if you find this is helpful then don't forget to accept this answer. or if you need any further assistance about api call or Json parsing, add/post your comment

Answer (score 0):

try to use ContentValues like this way

```
ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
values.put("username",name);
values.put("password",password);
```

OR
Use MultipartEntity

```
MultipartEntity multi = new MultipartEntity();
multi.addPart("name", new StringBody("your data"));
multi.addPart("Id", new StringBody("123"));
```

Answer (score 0):

here's an example for http post using AsyncTask:

```
public class httpSendrequest extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nvPairs=new ArrayList<>();

    Boolean error=false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            //here you initialize your json object and add it to value pairs
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();

    try {       
            JSONObject userCredentials = new JSONObject();
            userCredentials.put("nickname","nickname6");
            userCredentials.put("password","1234");

            jObj.put("user", userCredentials);
    nvPairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("jsonstring",jObj.toString()));
    } catch(Exception e) {
      error=true;
    }

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

    if(!error)
            try{

                String link ="http://"+ip+"/QSystem.asmx/insert_answer" ;
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(link); //adding URL to the http post
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvPairs, HTTP.UTF_8)); //adding the value pairs and encoding to the http post request
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();


            } catch (Exception e){
                error=true;
            }

            return "str";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);

            if(!error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }

    }
```

then you can call it from onCreate or in an OnClickListener for a button, like this:

```
new httpSendrequest().execute();
```

hope this helps :)